# Django is_valid() not working with modelformset_factory

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've created a simple contact form using the modelformset_factory to build the form in the view using the DB model.  The issue that I am having is that the **is_valid()** check before the save() is not working.  When I submit the form with empty fields it still passes the **is_valid()** and attempts to write to the DB.

I would like the is_valid() check to fail when the fields are empty so that the user can be directed to the form again with an error message. I believe that there is a simple solution to this.  Do you know what I am missing in my code?

Thanks.

Code:

**models.py**

```
class Response(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Your Name:')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Email:')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Phone Number:')
    apt_size = models.CharField(max_length=25,
                                choices=APT_CHOICES,
                                verbose_name='Apt Size:')
    movein_at= models.DateField(verbose_name='Desired Move-In Date')
    community = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                 choices=COMMUNITY_CHOICES,
                                 verbose_name='Community You Are Interested In:')
    referred_by = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                   choices=REFERRED_CHOICES,
                                   verbose_name='Found Us Where?')
    referred_other = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=50,verbose_name='If Other:')
    comments = models.TextField(verbose_name='Comments:')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from summitpark.contact.models import * 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def form(request):
    contact_form_set = modelformset_factory(Response,fields=('name','email','phone',
                                                            'apt_size','movein_at',
                                                            'community','referred_by',
                                                            'comments'),
                                                    exclude=('id'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = contact_form_set(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return render_to_response('contact/confirm.html')
        else: 
            return render_to_response('contact/form.html',{'formset':formset})
    else:
        formset = contact_form_set(queryset=Response.objects.none())
        return render_to_response('contact/form.html',{'formset':formset}
```

**Solution:**

```
class BaseContactFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
def clean(self):
    if any(self.errors):
        return
    for form in self.forms:
        name = form['name'].data
        if not name:
            raise forms.ValidationError, "Please Complete the Required Fields
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that providing 0 items is a valid formset, there is no minimum validation.  I'd provide a custom BaseModelFormset subclass that's clean() method just checked for a minimum of one obj.

Comment: Your solution worked but I am not able to display the error messages in the view.  Any ideas?

Comment: I realized I wasn't displaying {{ formset.non_form_errors }} in the view.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you really want a `formset`?  I suspect if you have a contacts form with only one instance of the `Response` in then you want a `ModelForm`...

```
class ResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields=('name','email','phone',
               'apt_size','movein_at',
               'community','referred_by',
               'comments')
```

As for which fields are allowed to be blank and which aren't, make sure it does the right thing in the admin first, then the `ModelForm` will do exactly the right thing (that is how the admin makes its forms after all).